# How to deselect all tabs in QTabBar?

Tags: qt, tabbar

Is there a way to deselect all tabs of a QTabBar? In the documentation it reads somewhat vague:

> The current index is -1 if there is no current tab.

But setting the current index to -1 seems not to have the effect of deselecting all tabs.

My use case is that I have tabbar driven toolbars. I also implemented the feature that all toolbars are hidden when the current tabbar tab is clicked again. However, I seem to be unable to get the respective visual effect of showing no tab selected.

Comment: Are you using setter: QTabBar::setCurrentIndex(int index) for set -1 value?

Comment: @Nikxp Yes, that is what I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution. An invisible fake tab does the trick. Tested with Qt 6.1.3 on Linux & Mac. Not sure about Qt5.

```
const auto fakeTabIndex = tabBar->addTab(QString());
tabBar->setTabVisible(fakeTabIndex, false);
....
tabBar->setCurrentIndex(fakeTabIndex);
```

Comment: Great, that actually seems to work. Sorry for the delayed reaction. And works at least with 5.15.2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Please see Nikolay's answer for a (tricky) work-around.*

I'm afraid this is currently not possible. `currentIndex` may only be `-1` when there are no enabled tab items.

Although it is not clearly mentioned in the docs, the source code is pretty clear:

```
bool validIndex(int index) const { return index >= 0 && index < tabList.count(); }

void QTabBar::setCurrentIndex(int index)
{
    Q_D(QTabBar);
    if (d->dragInProgress && d->pressedIndex != -1)
        return;
    int oldIndex = d->currentIndex;
    if (d->validIndex(index) && d->currentIndex != index) {
        ...
    }
}
```

<strike>A (tricky) work-around may be to disable all the tab items and to enable them again when the users clicks on it.</strike>

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Unfortunately, disabling is no option because it suggest that the tabs cannot be clicked. At least I'll try to file a bug/enhancement report.

Comment: @Daniel If you catch the click event yourself, you may be able to enable the tab JIT. Filing a feature is a good idea, but I'm afraid it will not be handled soon. Including a patch yourself may speed up the process.

Comment: I don't get the comment about enabling again. That would make the tab appear selected again.

Comment: @Daniel Isn't that what you want at the moment the user clicks on a tab?

Comment: The user clicks on an already selected tab which should brings it to the state of no tab being selected. This is changed again only after the user clicks again on a tab. (Think: Ribbon as in MS Word.)

Comment: The situation of 'unselecting' a tab could be detected by connecting to the `tabBarClicked` and testing whether the clicked tab equals the current tab.

Comment: Thanks. But that might be a misunderstanding. I have already implemented what you suggest. The problem is to make all tabs look non-selected. And, as far as I can see, this cannot be achieved by disabled because either they look deactivated or when re-enabled a tab will look selected.